# Multipart-form (image,parameters,headers) Post request with Alamofire in swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Firstly, i want to say i am new to swift, and know a little.So any help would be appriciated. I have a multipart-data form which has a image (profile-image), a few parameters (first-name, last-name) and headers(userid, hashCode). I want to send a POST request to submit the form.

I have been able to make POST request with only, headers and other parameters except image as:

```
let headers = [
        "user_id": (Helper.getUserInfo()?.user_id)!,
        "hash_code":(Helper.getUserInfo()?.hash_code)!,
    ]
let params = [
        "name": self.name.text!,
        "address":self.address.text!]


    Alamofire.request(.POST, kFormUrl, parameters:params ,headers:headers).responseJSON { [weak self] response in

//working fine
}
```

But how to send image as a file (not base-64string) i.e. direct file upload with parameters and headers.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use **Alamofire 3.0+** below code

```
func uploadImageAndData(){
//parameters
 let gender    = "M"
let firstName = "firstName"
let lastName  = "lastName"
let dob       = "11-Jan-2000"
let aboutme   = "aboutme"
let token     = "token"


var parameters = [String:AnyObject]()
parameters = ["gender":gender,"firstName":firstName,"dob":dob,"aboutme":aboutme,"token":token,"lastName":lastName]

let URL = "http://yourserviceurl/"
let image = UIImage(named: "image.png")

Alamofire.upload(.POST, URL, multipartFormData: {
  multipartFormData in
if  let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6) {
 multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "image", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
}
for (key, value) in parameters {
 multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
}
}, encodingCompletion: {
 encodingResult in

 switch encodingResult {
  case .Success(let upload, _, _):
     print("s")
    upload.responseJSON { response in
        print(response.request)  // original URL request
        print(response.response) // URL response
        print(response.data)     // server data
        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(JSON)")
        }
}

  case .Failure(let encodingError):
   print(encodingError)
    }
 })
}
```

Comment: Alamofire 4.0 Example?

Comment: How to add headers in multiform data in Almofire 3.0?

Comment: @Amit Gupta, can you give me an example for Alamofire 4.0?

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809867/alamofire-4-upload-with-parameters) for those who are looking for Alamofire 4

Answer (score 1):

```
   let userImageURL = NSURL(string: "your image url" as String)
        let data = NSData.init(contentsOfURL: userImageURL!)


Alamofire.upload(
                .POST,registerUrl!,
                multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data:"N".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"flag")

                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: data!, name: "image", fileName: "pic.jpg", mimeType: "image/png")

multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: facebookId.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"facebook_id")

                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: nameString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"first_name")


},
                encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                    switch encodingResult {
                    case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                        upload.responseJSON { response in
                            print(response)
                            let dict = response.result.value as! NSDictionary

                        }
                    case .Failure(let encodingError):
                        print(encodingError)
                    }
                }
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

I use Alamofire (Swift 2.3) to send multipart with progress.

```
func upload(URLRequest: Router, onProgress: (progress: Float?) -> Void, completion: (json: AnyObject?, error: Error?) -> Void) {
    let headers:[String: String] = [:]

    let router = URLRequest.URLRequest
    let tuple = URLRequest.parameters
    let parameters = tuple.0!
    let imagesData = tuple.1
    let url = router.URLString

    self.manager!.upload(
        .POST,
        url,
        headers: headers,
        multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData: MultipartFormData) -> Void in
            for value in imagesData {
                var mimeType = "video/jpg"
                var bodyName = "images"
                let filename = value.uniqueName
                if value.mediaType == ReporterMediaType.image {
                    mimeType = "image/jpg"
                    bodyName = "images"
                } else if value.mediaType == ReporterMediaType.video {
                    mimeType = "video/quicktime"
                    bodyName = "video"
                } else if value.mediaType == ReporterMediaType.videoFrame {
                    mimeType = "image/jpg"
                    bodyName = "videoFrame"
                }
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(
                    data: value.data,
                    name: bodyName,
                    fileName: filename,
                    mimeType: mimeType)
            }
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
            }
        },
        encodingCompletion: { (encodingResult) -> Void in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    if response.result.isSuccess || response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
                        completion(json: upload, error: nil)
                    } else {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            completion(json: nil, error: response.result.error)
                        }
                    }
                }
                upload.progress { _, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
                    let progress = Float(totalBytesRead)/Float(totalBytesExpectedToRead)
                    onProgress(progress: progress)
                }
            case .Failure:
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                break
            }
    }) }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func multipartImage(data:Data?, url:String,jsonInput:[String: String],controller:UIViewController, completion: @escaping (_ result: DataResponse<Any>) -> Void) {
var headers = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
    headers["Headerkey"] = "Headerkey"

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:
            { (multipartFormData) in

                if data != nil {
                    multipartFormData.append(data!, withName:"user_image", fileName:"image.jpg", mimeType:"image/jpeg")
                }else{
                    multipartFormData.append("".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "user_image")
                }

                for (key, value) in jsonInput
                {
                    multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
                }
        }, to:url, method: .post, headers: headers)
        { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _ , _ ):
                upload.uploadProgress(closure:
                    { (progress) in
                        print(String(format:"%.0f%@",Float(progress.fractionCompleted)*100,"%")))

                })

                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    if showLoader == true
                    {
                        MBProgressHUD.hide(for: controller.view, animated: true)
                    }

                    completion(response)

                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError.localizedDescription)

                break
            }
        }
    }
```