# cannot Uploading text file via Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to test upload speed via `Alamofire`, sending a file text to a server. tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809867/alamofire-4-upload-with-parameters) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31949118/send-post-parameters-with-multipartformdata-using-alamofire-in-ios-swift) but cannot make it work, which kind of data should I use for **myFile.txt**? do I need a php script somewhere?

```
   let parameters = ["file_name": "myFile.txt"]
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

        //I cannot substitute this line of code

        //     multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.photoImageView.image!, 1)!, withName: "photo_path", fileName: "swift_file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")

        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
        }
    }, to:"example.com")
    { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                //Print progress
                print("in progress...")
            })

            upload.responseJSON { response in
                //print response.result
                print(response)
            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            //print encodingError.description
            print("error")
        }
```

Comment: I cannot find your comment anymore, did you say Alamofire cannot upload file text? do you think I could do the same test by using image?

Answer (score 2):

```
   Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: {

        multipartFormData in

        if IMAGE_DATA_HERE.count > 0 {

            multipartFormData.append((IMAGE_DATA_HERE), withName: "image", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }
   }, to: API_URL_HERE, method:.post, headers:nil, encodingCompletion: {
        encodingResult in

        switch encodingResult {

            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.uploadProgress { progress in

                    //For Upload Progress
                }

                upload.responseJSON { response in

                   //For JSON Response
                }

            case .failure(let encodingError):

                print(encodingError, logLevel: .DEBUG)
            }
    })
```

Comment: API_URL_HERE is simply a folder on web url o do I need something else?  and what should I put on image data? I'm using an image "image.jpg" I just dragged and dropped in the project.